# Transpose a tab-separated file Python

Tags: python, transpose, csv

Is there a python module that can transpose a tab-separated file that has a mixture of characters and digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yes there is a python module to do that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that. I didn't know csv module can handle tab-delimited files too. I'm a Python newbie. I apologize for my ignorance.